# Why ColumnTransformer does not call fit on its transformers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have defined data for fitting with one categorical feature "sex":

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [25,19, 17],
    'sex': ['female', 'male', 'female'],
    'won_lottery': [False, True, False]
})
X = data[['age', 'sex']]
y = data['won_lottery']
```

and pipeline for transforming categorical features:

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
cat_transformers = Pipeline([
    ('onehot', ohe)
])
```

When fitting `cat_transformers` with data directly

```
cat_transformers.fit(X[['sex']], y)
print(ohe.get_feature_names())
```

I am able to get names of output features created by `OneHotEncoder` instance:

```
['x0_female' 'x0_male']
```

However, if I encapsulate `cat_transformers` into `ColumnTransformer`:

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('cat', cat_transformers, ['sex'])
    ]
)
preprocessor.fit(X, y)
print(ohe.get_feature_names())
```

it fails with

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This OneHotEncoder instance is not fitted yet. 
  Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

I would expect that calling `fit()` on `ColumnTransformer` causes calling `fit()` on all its transformers.

Why it does not work this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I understand it now. I was fitting one instance of `OneHotEncoder` and checking features on another instance:

```
print(id(ohe))
print(id(preprocessor.named_transformers_['cat'].named_steps['onehot']))

2757198591872
2755226729104
```

It looks like `ColumnTranformer` clones its transformers before fitting.

Comment: I have also used my `OneHotEncoder` inside `ColumnTransformer` and I need the features names but I also get `NotFittedError`. What is your workaround? Do you know why `ColumnTranformer` clones its transformers before fitting? I find it strange. From the docs (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html), "Enabling caching triggers a clone of the transformers before fitting. " but we are not caching here...

Comment: I wish we were closer to understanding how to get the feature names

Comment: @hipoglucido use `transformer_` see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63039383/5817977

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but I came to see how OHE names could be obtained from a `ColumnTransformer`

(Thanks @skibee). You have to use `transformer_` instead.

```py
# assuming that your OHE is in that index position 
preprocessor.transformers_[2][1][1].get_feature_names()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what [Gonzalo Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6302709/gonzalo-garcia) said. I think what's happening is that the `transformers` parameter from the `__init__` method is being tucked away in the `transformers` attribute of the class. Looking at the [ColumnTransformer documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), it calls out `transformers_` as the actual attribute name we are supposed to use to access the transformer objects.

It might have made sense to tuck the parameters away in hidden attributes to avoid the confusion, but that's for a future version I suppose!