# Sklearn pipeline not fitted after .fit has been called?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, sklearn-pandas

I have a simple pipeline like this

```
pl = Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessor", ColumnTransformer(
                      transformers=[
                     ('num', Pipeline(steps=[('StandardScaler', StandardScaler())]), selector(dtype_exclude="category")),
                     ('cat', Pipeline(steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder( sparse = False, handle_unknown='ignore' ))]), selector(dtype_include="category"))])),
               ('LR', LogisticRegression(max_iter = 1000, intercept_scaling = 1))])
```

I then call pl.fit on my training data, but when I try to check the onehot encoder to get variable names I keep getting an error message that it hasnt been fitted yet

```
pl.fit(X_train.drop(['ID'],axis = 1), y_train)
pl.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers[1][1].named_steps['onehot'].get_feature_names()

>> This OneHotEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

And checking confirms it has not been fitted. What am I missing?

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted

try:
    check_is_fitted(pl)
except:
    print('not fitted')

>> not fitted
```

Comment: please provide minimal reproducible example: dataframe and all code (include imports, for example)

Comment: `Pipeline`s don't set any attributes at fit time, so they will always fail `check_is_fitted`.  As for the rest, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58704347/10495893

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sklearn components in pipeline is not fitted even if the whole pipeline is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704347/sklearn-components-in-pipeline-is-not-fitted-even-if-the-whole-pipeline-is)