# sklearn "Pipeline instance is not fitted yet." error, even though it is

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

A similar question is already asked, but the answer did not help me solve my problem: [Sklearn components in pipeline is not fitted even if the whole pipeline is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704347/sklearn-components-in-pipeline-is-not-fitted-even-if-the-whole-pipeline-is)

I'm trying to use multiple pipelines to preprocess my data with a One Hot Encoder for categorical and numerical data (as suggested in [this blog](https://adhikary.net/en/2019/03/23/categorical-and-numeric-data-in-scikit-learn-pipelines/)).

Here is my code, and even though my classifier produces 78% accuracy, I can't figure out why I cannot plot the decision-tree I'm training and what can help me fix the problem. Here is the code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.tree as tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder  
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer


X = pd.DataFrame(data=data)  
Y = pd.DataFrame(data=prediction)

categoricalFeatures = ["race", "gender"]
numericalFeatures = ["age", "number_of_actions"]

categoricalTransformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
])

numericTransformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num', numericTransformer, numericalFeatures),
    ('cat', categoricalTransformer, categoricalFeatures)
])

classifier = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('classifier', tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3))
])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=12, stratify=Y)

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("model score: %.3f" % classifier.score(X_test, y_test))  # Prints accuracy of 0.78

text_representation = tree.export_text(classifier)
```

The last command produces this error, in spite of the model being fitted (I assume it's a synchronization situation but can't figure out how to solve it):

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This Pipeline instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: Error aside, you don't need a pipeline for the `categoricalTransformer`. You can use the OneHotEncoder directly like this: `categoricalTransformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `export_text` function on the whole pipeline as it only accepts Decision Tree objects, i.e. `DecisionTreeClassifier` or `DecisionTreeRegressor`. Only pass the fitted estimator of your pipeline and it will work:

```py
text_representation = tree.export_text(classifier['classifier'])
```

The error message stating that the `Pipeline` object is not fitted is due to the [`check_is_fitted`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460dbf19e5e196b8ef48f9712b72a3b3c3/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L1035) function of `scikit-learn`. It works by checking the presence of fitted attributes (ending with a trailing underscore) on the estimator. Since `Pipeline` objects do not expose such attributes, the check fails and raises the error, although it is indeed fitted. But that is not a problem since `Pipeline` objects are not meant to be used that way anyway.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much for your quick and complete response, @afsharov ! Follow-up question: is there a way to actually get the new list of feature names using this pipeline? (based on the one hot encoder in the pipeline?)

Comment: Never mind! Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646709/sklearn-pipeline-get-feature-names-after-onehotencode-in-columntransformer) that in my case, will work as below:
`classifier['preprocessor'].transformers_[1][1]['onehot']\
                   .get_feature_names(categoricalFeatures)`