# Plot best decision tree with pipeline and GridsearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I have GridsearchCV with a pipeline using decision tree as estimator

Now i want to plot the decision tree corresponding to the best_estimator of the GridsearchCV

There are some replys on stackoverflow but none consider a pipeline inside the GridsearchCV

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor, plot_tree
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np


#Dummy data
X= [[1,2,3,5], [3,4,5,6], [6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,5], [3,4,5,6], [6,7,8,9]]
y= [50,70,80,2,5,6]

scr = StandardScaler()
dtree = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=100)

pipeline_tree = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', scr),
    ('regressor', dtree)
])

param_grid_tree = [{
    'regressor__max_depth': [2, 3],
    'regressor__min_samples_split': [2, 3],
}]
GridSearchCV_tree = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline_tree,
                                 param_grid=param_grid_tree, cv=2)


Dtree = GridSearchCV_tree.fit(X, y)


plot_tree(Dtree.best_estimator_, max_depth=5,
          impurity=True,
          feature_names=('X'),
          precision=1, filled=True)
```

I get

```
NotFittedError: This Pipeline instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since your estimators are `Pipeline` objects, the `best_estimator_` attribute will return a pipeline as well. You have to further access the correct step with your regressor by indexing it, for example:

```py
plot_tree(
    Dtree.best_estimator_['regressor'],  # <-- added indexing here
    max_depth=5,
    impurity=True,
    feature_names=['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4'],   # changed this argument to make it work properly
    precision=1,
    filled=True
)
```

See the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#accessing-steps) on different methods to access pipeline steps.

In case you are wondering why your error message says the pipeline is not fitted, you can read more about it in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943229/sklearn-pipeline-instance-is-not-fitted-yet-error-even-though-it-is/67943910#67943910).

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution:

I have to use `Dtree.best_estimator_['regressor']` instead of  `Dtree.best_estimator`:

```
plot_tree(Dtree.best_estimator_, max_depth=5,
          impurity=True,
          feature_names=('X'),
          precision=1, filled=True)
```